# Downloading Qualtrics user-submitted files from API response in R

Tags: r, httr, qualtrics

probably a bit of a noob question but I've managed to get a successful response from the Qualtrics API using a url like this: https://yul1.qualtrics.com/API/v3/surveys/survey-id/responses/response-id/uploaded-files/file-id

My question is how to save the file that has been downloaded by the request to a given file path?

FYI `` response$headers$`content-disposition`[1] `` does return an accurate filename so am confident the call has worked correctly.

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's about `{httr}`, you can use `httr::write_disk()` to store response body in a file:

```r
httr::GET("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/r-lib/httr/main/tests/testthat/data.txt",
          httr::write_disk("data.txt"))
#> Response [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/r-lib/httr/main/tests/testthat/data.txt]
#>   Date: 2023-08-24 08:43
#>   Status: 200
#>   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
#>   Size: 12 B
#> <ON DISK>  ~\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcdZrWa\reprex-454011914356-cilia-stag\data.txt
fs::file_info("data.txt")[,1:3]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   path       type         size
#>   <fs::path> <fct> <fs::bytes>
#> 1 data.txt   file           12
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>